# Приложение на WebView и ошибки на подобии ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECT

Tags: webview

В общем вопрос таков. При использовании приложения и потере соединения появляется ошибка
[image: СКРИН]
Можно ли обработать эту ошибку для показа своей страницы?
Пробовал метод onReceivedError не помогло. Помогите пожалуйста, код прилагается

```js
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Game_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private long backPressedTime;
    private Toast backToast;

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);




        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        SimpleWebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new SimpleWebViewClientImpl(this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);



        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        //Проверяем подключение
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();


        if (networkInfo == null || !networkInfo.isConnected() || !networkInfo.isAvailable()){

            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            //Показываем диалог
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog);

            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

            dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations =
                    android.R.style.Animation_Dialog;

            Button btTryAgain = dialog.findViewById(R.id.bt_try_again);

            btTryAgain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    recreate();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }else {
            //Если интернет есть загружаем сайт

            webView.loadUrl("https://URL/");

        }



    }


    public class myWebViewclient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }



        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){
            //Your code to do
            setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog);
        }
    }

    //Выход по дабл тапу кнопки Назад

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {


        if (backPressedTime + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            backToast.cancel();
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }else{
           backToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Нажмите еще раз для выхода", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           backToast.show();
        }

        backPressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

}
```

Comment: Возможно у вас устройство с api < 23. Для этого используется [устаревший метод](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#onReceivedError(android.webkit.WebView,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: Не помогло. Ошибка сохраняется. Устройсто Note 6 PRO